# Recompute running amount in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hi I would like to ask for help how to update the wrong data below into correct sum of each amount using mysql statement or php.

The logic is i would like to sum the amount of type 1 and 2 and the answer will be to the next row type 1. my goal is to update the wrong data in the table below

```
wrong data
some_id     amount      type
A           0           1
A           300         2
B           400         1
B           -17         2
C           383         1
C           -10         2
```

The equation is in row some_id A, with amount of 0 and 300 the sum is 300 where  should be in some_id B with type 1
then again sum of row some_id B, with amount of 300 and -17 sum is 283 where should be in some_id C with type 1 ...

```
so the correct data should be like this
some_id     amount      type
A           0           1
A           300         2
B           300         1
B           -17         2
C           283         1
C           -10         2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This requires the usage of `LAG()` functionality. What is your MySQL server version ? Do `SELECT Version();` and report the results.

Comment: thanks for the comment my version is 5.7.22